# forward return value of x-apikeyInfoFunc to operation

Tags: python, swagger, openapi

I'm using openapi to define my API. I just added this security schema:

```
  securitySchemes:
    api_key:
      type: apiKey
      name: X-Auth
      in: header
      x-apikeyInfoFunc: apikey_auth
```

where `apikey_auth` is defined like this

```
def apikey_auth(token, required_scopes):
    decrypted_token = None
    try:
        decrypted_token = mydecrypter.decrypt(token)
    except InvalidToken:
        raise OAuthProblem('Invalid token')

    return {'decrypted_token': decrypted_token}
```

Now i'd like to use this authentication for my actual endpoints which are defined in openapi like this:

```
/myendpoint
   get:
      operationId: operation
      #more stuff
      security:
      - api_key: []
```

When now calling `myendpoint` the authentication is being done and works as expected. What I would like to have now is the return value of `apikey_auth` being passed into the call of `operation` so i can access `decrypted_token` in `operation` like this:

```
def operation(decrypted_token):
    data = get_data_for_token(decrypted_token)
    return data
```

Does anyone have an idea if this is possible somehow without having an extra parameter in the endpoint defintion?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. For whatever reasons with these changes it works:

```
def apikey_auth(token, required_scopes):
    decrypted_token = None
    try:
        decrypted_token = mydecrypter.decrypt(token)
    except InvalidToken:
        raise OAuthProblem('Invalid token')

    return {'sub': decrypted_token}
```

```
def operation(user):
    data = get_data_for_token(user)
    return data
```

Comment: how did you manage to access the token value from the controller?

Comment: @Slartibartfast I see from debug messages that Connexion injects context parameters `user` and `token_info` to controller methods guarded by an apiKey security scheme. In my tests a controller method like `operation` receives the value of the `sub` key in the `user` parameter, and the dict returned by `apikey_auth` function in the `token_info` parameter.